# Windows on extended display moving to laptop screen when powered off

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors, external-display, extended-desktop

I attached a new monitor to my laptop and configured it to "Extend these displays". I can move applications from the laptop screen to new monitor, but when I turn off the monitor the application windows move to the laptop screen.

On a friend's setup he can turn off his monitor without the the windows moving to his laptop screen.

On another friend's Mac when he turns off the monitor the windows move to the laptop screen but when he powers on the monitor the windows move back to the monitor.

How can I keep the applications on the monitor there even when it's not on? Or have them move back to it when I power it on like the Mac?